# Запрет на авто создание новых сессий с произвольным названием

Tags: php

Если пользователь меняет значение куки под названием PHPSESSID, на сервере создаётся новая сессия именно с тем названием которое ввёл пользователь в куку PHPSESSID... Можно ли это запретить как то на стороне сервера?  Ведь логичнее было бы оставить только серверу возможность генерировать названия для новых сессий...

К примеру может существуют настройки для php которые заставили бы проверять передаваемые PHPSESSID от пользователя на существование, и если на сервере такой сессии не существует - чтобы сервер выдавал пользователю новую сессию с авто-сгенерированным названием.

```
<?
session_start();
echo session_id();
//Сервер выдал нам сессию типа 61kc4inq1ho82vp4pkrdrgm6q6l1nmfphuy
//теперь вручную меняем значение куки PHPSESSID на hello-admin
//Обновляем страницу и на сервере создаётся новая сессия с названием hello-admin
//И соответственно session_id() выдаёт теперь hello-admin
?>
```

Comment: При логине пользователя и первоначальном создании сессии генерируйте еще одну куку со случайным значением и записывайте это значение в сессию. После старта сессии проверяйте куку и значение из сессии.

Comment: Спасибо за идею как вариант думаю можно так делать.